# I have a program that needs to find combination of an array of numbers

Tags: c

Array of numbers {1,2,3,4,5}. The first part of the program divides the array into side A and B. This part works correctly. I need to calculate the combinations for each side A and Side B  divisions.

```
A         B
1         2,3,4,5
1,2         3,4,5
1,2,3         4,5 
1,2,3,4         5
```

For A(1) & B(2,3,4,5) there would be 5 combinations and for
    A(1,2) & B(3,4,5) there would be 10 combinations.

I know that I need to you recursion but can figure out how to generate the algorithm and code. I am confused. I added the code that I am using but it prints all 120 combinations. Following the rule, pick a 2 first then the 3, I should have 30 combinations.

```
void swap(int* arr, int a, int b)
{
    int tmp = arr[a];
    arr[a] = arr[b];
    arr[b] = tmp;
}


void permute(int *arr, int start, int end)
{
   int i;

    if (start == end) 
    {
       return;
    }

    permute(arr, start + 1, end);

    /* permute elements recursively */
    for (i = start + 1; i < end; i++)
    {
        if (arr[start] == arr[i]) continue; /* skip */
    {
        swap(arr, start, i);

        permute(arr, start + 1, end);

        swap(arr, start, i);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: How does A(1) B(2,3,4,5) result in 5 combinations?  I could see 4 combinations (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5) but maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by combination.

Comment: 1) 12345 2) 21345 3) 23145 4) 23415 5) 23451. You count the orginal array too.

Comment: Also I forgot, to say that I have to pick the left most item first division I have to pick 2 first before I can pick 3.

Comment: Information that the recursive function needs: array A, array B, an index into array A, the length of array A, an index into array B, the length of array B, an output array, an index into the output array. Some of those can be hidden. For example, you can avoid passing the length of array A or B by putting a 0 at the end of the array. And you should be able to calculate the index into the output array from the A and B indexes. The function should put an item from A into the output, and call itself recursively. Then put an item from B into the the output, and call itself recursively.

Comment: I have added the code. I keep getting all permutations.